# itextsharp: PDF form does not have a method

Tags: itext

I've been using itextsharp for many years to fill out my Schedule D tax forms with a program I wrote. On this years 2012 forms my program executes ok but when I tried to read the output pdf files in acrobat I get an error: "Form does not have a method". I get this error for every field in the form.

Since I've been running my program for the past 5 years it seems that the this years pdf forms have some new feature in them.

Anybody know what "Form does not have a method" means? Code examples to correct it?
Thanks.

Comment: You should provide some relevant code.

Comment: ... And (a link to) the form.